# Multisite, Subdomain, shared NFS directory Linux HELP

Tags: multisite, redirect, subdomains

It's been about 3 months now and I cannot get things working. I am installing WordPress 4.4.1. I have two web servers, one SQL server and one NAS shared directory for files.

I install WordPress on the two webservers pointing their wp-config.php to the SQL server. This appears to work fine. A load balancing IP points to each.

I have a folder in my html folder called "blog" which is really a NAS share.
I follow the instructions in the codex to make this work and it does.

Now when I start configuring the multisite is where issues arrise. I setup a wildcard DNS entry before anything else. I turn on the option in wp-config.php by adding the following:

/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

Then I return to the site and do the network setup. I choose subdomain. I then copy the code provided to the index.php and .htaccess files.

When I log out and back in it looks fine. I can click and open all pages on the left related to the main site. At the top I have My Sites and the Main site. When I click anything related to My Sites or it's submenu Network Admin the links do not include the full path (the /blog after the .com). I've noticed I can get around this by entering the /blog in myself. That works for some navigation but I cannot create any sites. When I click create I'm redirected to a login. I've probably reinstalled and started from scratch 10+ times.  I've made lots of changes to .htaccess, wp-config.php and index.php but none have done the trick.  Seems like a couple issues and trust me I have looked EVERYWHERE but know I've read some really good advise here and hoping someone has a clue.

Site is http://wp.ravanallc.com/ if that helps at all.

Thank you for reading!